# bashにインストールした Python 3.x が表示されない

Tags: python, macos

macOSで最近プログラミングを始めた初心者です。

最初に誤って、Python3.8.5と3.7.6をインストールしてしまいました。おまけに、macには最初から2.7.1が入っているため、合計で三つのPythonがパソコンの中にあります。

問題は、bashに3.7.6と2.7.1しか認識されない点です。つまり、bashに `python --version` と打ち込むと、3.7.6と出て、3.7.6をゴミ箱に入れると `python --version` の結果は2.7.1となります。

対話シェルや他のテキストエディタにはPython3.8.5でコーディングしている扱いになっているので、bashにも、現在使用しているのはPython3.8.5だと認識させたいのですが、どうすれば良いでしょうか？

Comment: 念のため、どんな手順で Python 3.x をインストールしたかも提示しておくとよいかもしれません。(mac は詳しくないですが、ゴミ箱に入れるのは正しい手順なのか少し不安です) / また、基本的には Python **2.x** と **3.x** は区別されており、python 3.x を呼び出したい場合は明示的に `python3` とする必要があったと思います。

Comment: 現状の把握としてこの記事が参考になるのでは？ [What version of Python is on my Mac?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33175827/9014308)

Comment: ありがとうございます。おっしゃられたようにやると、3.8.5が表示されました。しかし以前は python --versionだけで3.7.6が表示されていたのが気がかりです…。何か可能性はありませんか？